# Actuarial exercise using R

Tags: r

With ?? money a year the clients can buy free service for the first damage that will occur within a year as long as the miles are less than 14.

**Data:**

- Miles: normal distribution with `mean=16` and `var=2.5` if it is the only car in the family while if it is the second car the distribution is a normal distribution with  `mean=8` and `var=15`, 60% of customers also have a second car, suppose no one has a third.
- First damage (in months): follows exponential distribution with an average value of `20`
- Amount of the damage : follows gamma distribution with `mean=100` and `variance= 10000`.

**My question is : What fee should the clients pay so that with 99% probability the company will not be harmed, if there are exactly 10 customers a year?**

I wrote my code, but I don't know if it is correct and how I should continue

```
cost <- vector("numeric", 10000)

for (i in 1:10000) {
  n <- 10
  miles <- 0.4 * rnorm(n, 16, sqrt(2.5)) + 0.6 * rnorm(n, 8, sqrt(15))
  miles <- (miles>=0) * miles + (miles<0) * 0 
  firstdamage <- rexp(n, 1/20)
  damage <- rgamma(n, shape=1, scale=100)
  clientstopay <- ((firstdamage < 12) & (miles < 14))
  cost[i] <- sum(clientstopay * damage) / n
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you did not simulate whether the second car exists or not. Consider the following simulation procedure. We use parallal processing for better efficiency.

```
library(future.apply)

cost_per_customer <- function(n) {
  n_ <- rbinom(1L, n, 0.6)
  miles <- c(rnorm(n, 16, sqrt(2.5)), rnorm(n_, 8, sqrt(15)))
  mon <- rexp(n + n_, 1 / 20)
  amt <- rgamma(n + n_, shape = 1, scale = 100)
  sum(amt[mon <= 12 & miles < 14]) / n
}

simu <- function(n, yrs) future_replicate(yrs, cost_per_customer(n))

plan(multisession)
res <- simu(10, 1e6)
quantile(res, 0.99)
```

Here, function `cost_per_customer` is the key. Let *n_* be the number of people having a second car. It is evident that *n_* follows the binomial distribution *B(n, 0.6)*. We then generate miles, damage time and damage amount for all *n + n_* cars accordingly, sum the damage amounts of those cars satisfying the conditions you stated, and divide the sum by **n** (not **n + n_** because we only have **n** customers).

After creating this function, the rest is just running simulations repeatedly and calculating the 99% quantile of the simulated distribution. The distribution looks like this

[image: hist]

The 99% quantile is

```
> quantile(res, 0.99)
     99% 
102.0923
```

Note that you may get a different number, but it should be around 102.